# What does "[&]" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading a source code and it contains the following lines.

```
auto updateSlack = [&](const char slack_type, const double s) {
    if (slack_type == 'e') {
        wns.early_slack = min(s, wns.early_slack);
        tns.early_slack += s;
    }
    else if (slack_type == 'l') {
        wns.late_slack = min(s, wns.late_slack);
        tns.late_slack += s;
    }
};
```

I am confused with the "[&]" symbol after "=" operator. Can anyone tell what exactly this suggests?

Comment: It's a lambda function, if this should be the thing confusing you.

Comment: [Lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: So what exactly are you confused about? The code updates "slack" based on the slack type and the supplied (assuming slack) value.

Comment: What _part_ of this code confuses you?

Comment: [Slack explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNmPamZelVQ)

Comment: got it guys..... I just wanted to know the name of this structure. Never seen this type of statements before. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @AvirupMullick "this structure", as a whole, is a variable declaration. I can't believe that you really haven't seen a variable declaration before; I guess you're probably talking about the lambda expression. That's the problem with your question (and why it has so many downvotes) - it wasn't clear what you were asking. If you'd said for eg "what does the part beginning with [&] mean?" it would have been clearer.

Comment: @davmac yes I was asking about the [&] sign before the arguments. Like I have seen normal function declaration but this was somewhat confusing at the first.

Comment: @AvirupMullick my point is that you need to make this clear _in the question_. It's not too late to edit the question and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement uses a lambda expression.

```
auto updateSlack = [&](const char slack_type, const double s) {
    if (slack_type == 'e') {
        wns.early_slack = min(s, wns.early_slack);
        tns.early_slack += s;
    }
    else if (slack_type == 'l') {
        wns.late_slack = min(s, wns.late_slack);
        tns.late_slack += s;
    }
};
```

The compiler does two things. The first one is that the compiler defines an unnamed class that will contain function call operator that corresponds to the body of the lambda expression.

The second one is that the compiler creates an object of this class and assign it to variable `updateSlack`.

You can imagine this the following way

```
struct  
{
    auto &r1 = wns;
    auto &r2 = tns;

   void operator ()( const char slack_type, const double s ) const
   {
        if (slack_type == 'e') {
            wns.early_slack = min(s, wns.early_slack);
            tns.early_slack += s;
        }
        else if (slack_type == 'l') {
            wns.late_slack = min(s, wns.late_slack);
            tns.late_slack += s;
        }
    }
} updateSlack;
```

Then you can call the function call operator of the object somewhere in the program where a functional object is needed like

```
updateSlack( 'l', 10.10 );
```

Answer (score 6):

What you have shown is a variable declaration.

- `auto` means the type of the variable will be inferred.
- `updateSlack` is the name of the variable.
- `=` specifies that the variable will be initialized with some value (via copy-initialization).
- the remainder is a lambda expression, which constitutes the value to which the variable is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration being a [Lambda function](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html), with the & affecting the scope of variables used in it.